# How to train Stanford NLP NER Extraction model to skip the repeating words?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to extract the NER from the text using **.NET Framework** and **StanFord NER Model**.
I have a text like

Hello, I am John Doe. Body Mass index is 27. And Body Surface Area is 2.3m.

For this i did create tsv file to train the model. Which is as under:

```
Hello   O
,   O
I   O
am  O
John    PERSON
Doe.    PERSON
Body    BMI
Mass    BMI
index   BMI
is  O
27. O
And O
Body    O
Surface O
Area    O
is  O
2.3m.   O
```

prop file is as under

```
trainFileList = train/standford_train.tsv
serializeTo = dummy-ner-model-eng.ser.gz
map = word=0,answer=1

useClassFeature=true
useWord=true
useNGrams=true
noMidNGrams=true
maxNGramLeng=6
usePrev=true
useNext=true
useSequences=true
usePrevSequences=true
maxLeft=1
useTypeSeqs=true
useTypeSeqs2=true
useTypeySequences=true
wordShape=chris2useLC
useDisjunctive=true
```

and using below java command

```
java -mx1g -cp stanford-ner.jar;lib/* edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -annotators 'tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,regexner' -prop train/prop.txt
```

So, the problem i am facing is Body with tagging BMI is coming two times because of repetition in **Body Mass Index** and **Body Surface Area**.

Is there any way that i can omit this second body tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to produce more training data that has examples with `Body` not labeled as `BMI`.  If you are only looking for specific patterns, you might get better results with a rule-based approach.  There are tools for rule based NER building in Stanford CoreNLP.

More info: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/tokensregex.html